# ASP.NET 4.0 dropDownList as select parameter - minimising queries sent to database

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, objectdatasource

This should be a basic question, and I assume a lack of precise search terms is the reason I cannot find an answer.

A database I am working on contains a small table with only about 6 rows and 5 fields. It does require CRUD functionality as it will change occasionally, but will almost certainly never expand beyond a dozen rows.

The ASP.NET web application has a business logic and data access layer.

I would like to have a dropDownList as the pseudo 'paging' control, to choose which row to display in a detailsView.

The quick and nasty solution solution is to put 2 objectDataSource controls in the ASP, one with a select parameter:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="DDDataSource" runat="server" TypeName="PICUdrugs.BLL.referenceBL"
SelectMethod="getReferences"/>
<asp:DropDownList ID="RefAbrevDDL" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
    DataTextField="abbrev" DataSourceID="DDDataSource" 
    DataValueField="drugReferenceID" ViewStateMode="Enabled" >
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="SelRefObjDataSrc" runat="server" SelectMethod="getReferences"
UpdateMethod="updateReference" DeleteMethod="deleteReference" TypeName="PICUdrugs.BLL.referenceBL"
OnUpdated="reference_CRUD" DataObjectTypeName="PICUdrugs.DAL.drugReference" 
ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues" OldValuesParameterFormatString="orig{0}">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:controlparameter name="refID" controlid="RefAbrevDDL" propertyname="SelectedValue"/>
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
<asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" />
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" DataSourceID="SelRefObjDataSrc"
    CssClass="DetailView">
    <Fields>
        <asp:DynamicField DataField="referenceDescription" HeaderText="Reference Description" />
        .....[remaining fields].....
```

While this works, it bothers me that I am querying the database twice for such similar information. Are there any efficient/neat solutions to take advantage of the objectDataSource (ie not having to write specific event handlers for the detailsView), but build an enumerable list on a single database query, and have both controls access the same object (? use the detailsView paging control?)? code behind is c#, but vb is fine if anyone has any examples/links.

Thank you for your thoughts (even if those thoughts are to stop being lazy, ditch both objectDataSources and just write the detailsview event handlers manually) - always appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a method, but please post an alternative if it is felt this is a bit hackish, or better solutions exist:

in the code behind file for the web page, set up a private variable so that a reference to the buisness layer object persists through the page build cycle, and set up object creating and created event handlers:

```
    private referenceBL persistentRef;
    protected void DDDataSource_ObjCreated(object sender, ObjectDataSourceEventArgs e)
    {
        persistentRef = e.ObjectInstance as referenceBL;
    }
    protected void SelRefObjDataSrc_ObjCreating(object sender, ObjectDataSourceEventArgs e)
    {
        if (persistentRef!=null)
        {
            e.ObjectInstance = persistentRef;
        }
    }
```

in the buisness layer, have a private variable pointing to the same enumerable list used by the first object data source, and handle the select as so:

```
    private IEnumerable<drugReference> persistingRef;
    public IEnumerable<drugReference> getReferences()
    {
        persistingRef = DrugRefRepository.getReferences();
        return persistingRef;
    }
    public IEnumerable<drugReference> getReferences(int refID)
    {
        if (persistingRef == null)
        {
            return DAL.DrugRefRepository.getReferences(refID); //data access layer method
        }
        else
        {
            return persistingRef.Where(r => r.drugReferenceID==refID);
        }
    }
```

Of course then disposing of the buisness object should be handled manually in order to close the database connection ASAP.

I am hoping to apply the same strategy to a nested (embedded) objectDataSource within a listView so that update and delete functionality exists, but minimising the number database calls.